# Corda - flow timeout

Tags: corda

According to the [docs](https://docs.corda.r3.com/api-flows.html#http-and-database-calls)...

> The call must be executed in a BLOCKING way. Flows don’t currently
>   support suspending to await the response to a call to an external
>   resource For this reason, **the call should be provided with a timeout
>   to prevent the flow from suspending forever.** If the timeout elapses,
>   this should be treated as a soft failure and handled by the flow’s
>   business logic

How do I create an initiator flow that times out if it does not receive a response in an allotted time? Are there any examples of this?

Comment: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#timeouts

Comment: @Kid101 that's a HTTP request timeout, which I'm already doing. What I want is a mechanism to cause the flow to timeout.

Comment: You can make your flow implement `TimedFlow` and then configure `flowtimeout` in `node.conf` (in Corda CE). ah, wait it may cause issues with `NotaryFlow` as well, as `flowtimeout` config is common to both.

Comment: if you are calling from web-server you can probably try something like this but this may work at the cost of inconsistent data: 
`try{
 flowHandle.getReturnValue().get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (Exception e) {
 if (e instanceof TimeoutException) {
  rpcOps.killFlow(flowHandle.getId());
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Corda 3, there is no mechanism for causing a flow to time out. When the docs say "the call should be provided with a timeout", this refers to the HTTP call.

The only alternative currently is to check how long the HTTP call has taken when the response is received, and throw an error in the flow if the time window is exceeded.